# Linux Mint 18 + Nvidia-375: modprobe: FATAL: Module nvidia_current not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic

Tags: linux, linux-mint, nvidia, proprietary-drivers, bumblebee

I've tried to install and configure nvidia drivers on Linux Mint 18 but still have errors.

Can anyone help me?

See some errors:

```
wellington@wellington-mint18 ~ $ cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | egrep -i "nvidia|nouveau"
[    18.063] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 0
[    18.063] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 1
[    18.063] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    18.064] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nvidia
[    18.064] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[    18.064] (II) Unloading nvidia
[    18.064] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
```

and

```
wellington@wellington-mint18 ~ $ sudo modprobe nvidia_current;
modprobe: FATAL: Module nvidia_current not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic
```

See scenario:

```
wellington@wellington-mint18 ~ $ uname -a
Linux wellington-mint18 4.4.0-21-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 18:33:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
wellington@wellington-mint18 ~ $ cat /etc/*release
DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18
DISTRIB_CODENAME=sarah
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 18 Sarah"
```

I tried too: https://gist.github.com/wellington1993/da8b51cae81a05156746bbc8e8304ec6

Comment: The ways to solve the problem(for this moment) is:

- Use the kernel 4.8.0-32-generic
- Update to Linux Mint 18.1 (Instead 18.0)
- Disable edge, beta, unstable repositories or lists
- Install the 367.57 driver version (Specific version)
- Follow https://gist.github.com/wellington1993/da8b51cae81a05156746bbc8e8304ec6 script

But I wait for more opinions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I read it from NVIDIA site.You didnt need to do modprobe nvidia-375.But you should add NOMODESET in GRUB when the display was not right.I did some searches for you.

Comment: It's correct but the NOMODESET only work on 18.1 (.1) I had 18.0 version. Anyway upgrade the distribution version is necessary.

Comment: I tried the "NOMODESET" but unfortunately it is not related to the problem.

Comment: But I accepted because solve other problems like that.

Comment: But if don't resolve try the comment with "gist" cited in the question.